# Azure Devops Create Pipeline (Classic way) REST API

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-devops

I am migrating an Azure devops organization to another organization,

I ran into a problem where i can not create a pipeline which created in the classic way (NOT A YAML).

This is the JSON

```json
{
    "name": "PP_NAME",
    "folder": "",
    "configuration": {
        "designerJson": {
            "options": [
                {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "definition": {
                        "id": "DEF_ID"
                    },
                    "inputs": {
                        "branchFilters": "[\"+refs/heads/*\"]",
                        "additionalFields": "{}"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "enabled": false,
                    "definition": {
                        "id": "DEF_ID"
                    },
                    "inputs": {
                        "workItemType": "Task",
                        "assignToRequestor": "true",
                        "additionalFields": "{}"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "variables": {
                "system.debug": {
                    "value": "false",
                    "allowOverride": true
                }
            },
            "tags": [],
            "process": {
                "phases": [
                    {
                        "name": "Agent job 1",
                        "refName": "Job_1",
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "target": {
                            "executionOptions": {
                                "type": 0
                            },
                            "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": false,
                            "type": 1
                        },
                        "jobAuthorizationScope": "project"
                    }
                ],
                "target": {
                    "agentSpecification": {
                        "identifier": "windows-2019"
                    }
                },
                "type": 1
            },
            "quality": "definition",
            "path": "\\",
            "repository": {
                "id": "REPOSITORY_ID",
                "name": "test 1",
                "type": "TfsGit"
            }
        },
        "path": "\\",
        "type": "designerJson"
    }
}
```

The output :

```
{
"$id": "1",
"innerException": null,
"message": "This API does not support creating pipelines of configuration type DesignerJson.",
"typeName": "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.UnsupportedConfigurationTypeException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi",
"typeKey": "UnsupportedConfigurationTypeException",
"errorCode": 0,
"eventId": 3000
}
```

According the the AZDO documentation, it is possible to create a pipeline with the classic way.

[image]

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a classic pipeline, you can use this REST API [Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)．

If you are not sure about the request body, you can use REST API [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to get the definition of a classic pipeline as a reference.

Comment: Isn't the 'Definitions' API is for releases ?

Comment: This API can also be used to create classic pipelines. Tested from my side, I can successfully create a classic build pipeline by using it.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, i succeeded creating pipelines :)

Comment: @ Shachar297 It's great to know my suggestion is helpful for you.  In order to let others who have the same question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!